# Test equality of multiple proportions

Tags: r, proportion, multi-class

Conciser a cross-tab like this (or equivalent just with different number of either classes or folds):

```
         Classes
       A  B  C  D
Fold1 12 10 12 14
Fold2 10 12 14 12
Fold3 14 10 12 12
Fold4 20 28 20 20
Fold5 14 10 12 12
```

How should one check, if proportions of classes' A, B, C, and D frequencies in each fold (i.e. proportions in each row) are (approximately) equal?
How can a solution be implemented in `R`?

`R` code to reproduce the table:

```
M <- matrix(c(12, 10, 12, 14,
              10, 12, 14, 12,
              14, 10, 12, 12,
              20, 28, 20, 20,
              14, 10, 12, 12),
           nrow = 5,
           byrow = TRUE,
           dimnames = list(paste0("Fold",1:5),LETTERS[1:4]))
```

Comment: you can perform the chi square test.

Comment: Right, just `chisq.test(M)`.